# If $a*b = xy-x-y+2$, show that $2$ is the identity element

Tags: abstract-algebra

I took an abstract algebra quiz today. I felt fairly comfortable going in, but I think I did poorly. One question stated that

> if $a*b = xy-x-y+2,$ show that $2$ is the identity element.

I realize that an identity element $e$ means that $s*e = s$.

I'm not sure where to go from here. If $x$ is $2$, then you're left with $y$, or if $2$ is $y$, then you're left with $x$. But that sounds stupid and can't be correct. It seems that if you plug in $2$, you should get $xy-x-y+2$, but I just don't see how.

Comment: On the left-hand side you have $a$'s and $b$'s but on the right hand side you have $x$'s and $y$'s.  Surely these should match somehow, otherwise how do $a$'s and $b$'s relate to $x$'s and $y$'s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little too long for a comment:

This quote from your question

> If x is 2, then you're left with y, or if 2 is y, then you're left
>   with x.

**is** the answer to your question. It shows that 2*x = x*2 = x .

Answer (score 1):

You say the question defines the operator '*' thus: a*b = **x.y - x - y + 2** (where '.' is the usual product). I suggest you reread the question - I believe what they say (or what they *meant to say*) is a*b = **a.b - a - b + 2** (or equivalently, x*y = x.y - x - y + 2).  In which case the proof that 2 is the identity is:

(left side) 2*b = 2.b - 2 - b + 2 = b

(right side) a*2 = a.2 - a - 2 + 2 = a

Comment: Are you the same user as the following other PMar: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/349761/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/347147/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/325605/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/344183/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/357091/pmar, http://math.stackexchange.com/users/358074/pmar. If this is the case, could you please [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts?

Comment: Seconding Watson's suggestion. If you lost your login credentials, then [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/account). It is good to keep all the reputation you earned with one account, because that account will then collect privileges that make participation on the site easier. Having multiple accounts may also later attract negative attention, because people are worried about the possibility of you voting for your own posts or some other unwanted scheming.

Comment: @PMar : here is a $7$-th (or $8$-th ?) account : https://math.stackexchange.com/users/370376.